# Highchart stockchart data from python

Tags: javascript, python, flask, highcharts

Hello I am working on drawing stock charts with Highchart stock example template. 
My problem is that I have the data from Python, and I feed the data to javascript using Flask.

Two data (list): one for time --> ['1493991000','1493991060','1493991120',...]
                 another one for values --> ['12.22','12.45','13.02',...].

Below is my Highstock code:

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  var seriesOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = {
      {
        ticker
      }
    };

/**
 * Create the chart when all data is loaded
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function createChart() {

  Highcharts.stockChart('chart_container', {

    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 2
    },

    yAxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
        }
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 2,
        color: 'silver'
      }]
    },

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        compare: 'percent',
        showInNavigator: true
      }
    },


    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
      valueDecimals: 2,
      split: true
    },

    series: seriesOptions
  });
}

$.each(names, function(i, name) {



  seriesOptions[i] = {
    name: name,
    data: pricerec# from python
  };

  // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
  // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
  seriesCounter += 1;

  if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
    createChart();
  }
});

< /script>
```

The pricerec is the price list my python code produces. This works fine with showing the prices. But I am not sure how should I associate this with the time on xAxis using my own time list from python.

Please let me know how should I do this.

Comment: see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/) and see its [data](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json). If possible try to process in server side and if not possible in server side then use array push() method to create desirable data (as in the example above) set in client side.

Comment: You should change xAxis.type to datetime and then zip your two lists into one array as folows [[timestamp, value], [timestamp, value], ...] Both values must be numbers